# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused - docker-compose exec app php artisan migrate

Tags: docker, mysql

Docker containers are up and running:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                   COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS                           PORTS                               NAMES
bf78987a0f5d        hakase-labs/laravel     "docker-php-entrypoi…"   56 minutes ago       Up 56 minutes                    9000/tcp                            app
d1fe2f9171bd        mysql:5.7               "docker-entrypoint.s…"   56 minutes ago       Up 56 minutes                    33060/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3312->3306/tcp   db
43f1025c1a59        nginx:alpine            "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   56 minutes ago       Restarting (1) 54 seconds ago                                        nginx
```

It's a Laravel install with `docker`, `mysql` and `nginx`. I want to run the migrations within the docker container i.e.

`docker-compose exec app php artisan migrate`

My database service is pretty straight forward; `docker-compose.yml`:

```
  #MySQL Service
  db:
   image: mysql:5.7
   container_name: db
   restart: unless-stopped
   tty: true
  ports:
   - "3312:3306"
  environment:
   MYSQL_DATABASE: laravel
   MYSQL_USER: laravel
   MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
   MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
  volumes:
   - mysqldata:/var/lib/mysql/
  networks:
   - mynet
```

`.env`:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3312
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=laravel
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

Things I've tried;

```
DB_HOST=mysql
```

and changing db port numbers

`docker-compose exec app php artisan config:clear` and `docker-compose exec app php artisan cache:clear`

Login to the container; `docker-compose exec app ash` and attempt to run the migrations from there - same error message applies.

but no dice. What's the problem with `artisan migrate` within a `docker` container?

EDIT:
I'm editing `.env` from within the container;

```
 docker-compose exec app vim .env
```

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:TWmjLcVOQFMIiKOKvtKQoFS/LMoH05ry/DF6148izL8=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=db
DB_PORT=3307
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=laravel
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

Thus propagating to my local copy.

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=db
DB_PORT=3307
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=laravel
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

Run it again and still no migrations;

```
$ docker-compose exec app php artisan cache:clear
 Application cache cleared!
$ docker-compose exec app php artisan config:clear
 Configuration cache cleared!
$ docker-compose exec app php artisan migrate

Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] 
 Connection refused (SQL: select *
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing you followd this tutorial [dockerizing-laravel-with-nginx-mysql-and-docker-compose](https://www.howtoforge.com/dockerizing-laravel-with-nginx-mysql-and-docker-compose/)

`DB_HOST` has to be the service-name you specified in your `docker-compose.yml` and `DB_PORT` needs to have the port you specify in the port-mapping.

when I edit `.env` file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=db          # <= service-name of db
DB_PORT=3306        # <= port-mapping from service: db
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=laravel
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

`./artisan migrate` gets a connection to the database.

Comment: I made your change, thanks. Same error message though sadly.

Comment: you also need to change the port - I edited my answer.

Comment: Please see my latest edit, thanks.

Comment: `docker-compose exec app ash` then `nc -zv db 3306` - if it says `db (172.28.0.4:3306) open` that's the hostname and port you need to connect to your database, if it's empty you won't get a connection. Notice, that you are trying to connnect to the internal port of the container `- external_port:internal_port`

Comment: From within the container; `$ nc -zv db 3306
db (172.18.0.4:3306) open` I understand this IP is where the db is - does this pair (IP & port) now need to go into one of my `.env` variables? Only, the `DB_HOST=db` is reserved right now for my msyql service container name.

Comment: From inside or outside the container and using ports `3306/3307` I now receive: `SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'laravel'@'172.18.0.2' (using password: YES)`

Comment: Now your first Problem is solved ! Try
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29362394/laravel-5-error-sqlstatehy000-1045-access-denied-for-user-homesteadlocal

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me. I think you might need to rebuild your container with `docker-compose up --build`. It might be useful for someone else.

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=db
DB_PORT=3306
```